# When can the order of a Ito integral and a.s. limit be interchanged

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

When can the order of a Ito integral and a.s. limit be interchanged i.e. assume you got
$Y_t^n\rightarrow Y_t$.

When can we say

$$\int\limits_0^t Y_t^n dW_s  \rightarrow \int\limits_0^t Y_t dW_s$$

I know dropped a lot of further explenations. But I think it is very clear from the context what I mean. But feel free to assume other conditions on the integrand ect.

Comment: Dominated convergence should be applicable here. Meaning, $Y^n$ should be dominated and $W_s$ integrable. The convergence of integrals should take place in probability. Can't promise convergence with probability $1$, though.

Comment: Thank you I think I know now how to takle this

Comment: The result mentioned by @AlvinL holds in greater generality for integration under semimartingales of predictable processes $Y^n$ convergent to some $Y$ pointwise, and $|Y^n|\leq K$ for some process $K$ predictable and locally bounded; then $(Y^n\cdot X)_t\to (Y\cdot X)_t $ for all $t\geq 0$. I can post a reference as answer if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $|Y^{n}|,|Y|\leq M$ or at least dominated $|Y^n_t-Y_t|^2\leq G$ for some $E[G]<\infty$.

By Markov

$$P\left[\int^{T} (Y^n_t-Y_t)dB_t\geq R\right]\leq \frac{1}{R}E\left(\int^{T} (Y^n_t-Y_t)dB_t\right)^{2},$$

and by Itô isometry we have

$$E\left(\int^{T} (Y^n_t-Y_t)dB_t\right)^{2}=\int^{T} E\left(Y^n_t-Y_t\right)^{2}dt.$$

Then we use
$$\begin{align*} \int |Y^n_t-Y_t|^2 \, d\mathbb{P} &= \int_{|Y^n_t-Y_t| \leq \epsilon} |Y^n_t-Y_t|^2 \, d\mathbb{P} + \int_{|Y^n_t-Y_t| > \epsilon} |Y^n_t-Y_t|^2 \, d\mathbb{P} \\ &\leq \epsilon^2 + (2M)^2 \mathbb{P}(|Y^n_t-Y_t|>\epsilon). \end{align*}$$

So here you need

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sup_{t\leq T}\mathbb{P}(|Y^n_t-Y_t|>\epsilon)=0.$$

If we just use dominated, the condition is

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sup_{t\leq T}\mathbb{E}G1_{|Y^n_t-Y_t|>\epsilon}=0.$$